# If Free Shipping Replace Text with Free instead of $0.00 in Magento 2

Tags: shipping-methods, shopping-cart, magento-2.1.3, free-shipping

I am trying to customize the shopping cart page, If customer select **Free Shipping** Shipping Method needs to replace **Free** instead of **$0.00**. For this stuff, I followed steps.

[image]

Customized the **root/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/cart/totals/shipping.html**, but it's not affecting.

Can you please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273844/show-free-shipping-text-instead-of-0-00/344975#344975

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my self.

**requirejs-config.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping':'Namespace_Modulename/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping',
            'Magento_Tax/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping':'Namespace_Modulename/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping'
        }
    }
};
```

**shipping.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ],
    function ($, Component, quote) {
        var displayMode = window.checkoutConfig.reviewShippingDisplayMode;
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                displayMode: displayMode,
                template: 'VLCSolutions_FreeShippingTxt/checkout/summary/shipping'
            },
           /* Added my functions */
           isFreeShipping:function(){
                var carrierCode = quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code;
                if(carrierCode == "customerpickup"){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            },
            getText:function(){
                return "Free";
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**shipping.html**

```
<!-- Added custom functions with core function -->
    <!-- ko if: isFreeShipping() -->
    <tr class="totals shipping excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: title"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getShippingMethodTitle()"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">
            <span  class="price" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;" data-bind="text: getText(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: isFreeShipping() -->
    <tr class="totals shipping excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: title"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getShippingMethodTitle()"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">
            <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

It's worked for me. If anyone has better answer update this or post new answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not change the root/vendor files. Try to create a module/theme to change the required file:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_intro.html

When i tried to change that area i had to overried the file 
root/vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used to get the value of shipping method and it's shipping amount by using below code `<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'],function($){

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('input:radio[class=radio]').change(function() {
                alert(this.value);
                console.log($('#free_shipping_text').text());
                console.log($('#free_shipping').text());
            });

        });

    });

</script>` but it's not working. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

More simple.

*requirejs-config.js*

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping': {
                'Namespace_Modulename/js/checkout-shipping-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

*\Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend\web\js\checkout-shipping-mixin.js*

```
define([], function () {
    var mixin = {

        /**
         * @return {*}
         */
        getValue: function () {
            var price;

            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return this.notCalculatedMessage;
            }
            price = this.totals()['shipping_amount'];

            if (price === 0) {
                return 'free';
            }

            return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
        }
    };

    return function (shipping) {
        return shipping.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```