# Show free shipping text instead of $ 0.00

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

Is there a way to show free shipping text instead of $ 0.00?

I tried with a couple of answers already posted on Magento StackExchange but none of them are working. Tried to change `shipping.js` to return free price instead of 0. Tried to manually change that span element but I can not access it with dom.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Override core price.js for shipping method into your theme.

path : /vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price.js

move the file in your theme

Replace below code :
    /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */

define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils'
], function (Component, quote, priceUtils) {
    'use strict';

```
return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_Tax/checkout/shipping_method/price'
    },
    isDisplayShippingPriceExclTax: window.checkoutConfig.isDisplayShippingPriceExclTax,
    isDisplayShippingBothPrices: window.checkoutConfig.isDisplayShippingBothPrices,

    /**
     * @param {Object} item
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    isPriceEqual: function (item) {
        return item['price_excl_tax'] != item['price_incl_tax']; //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
    },

    /**
     * @param {*} price
     * @return {*|String}
     */
    getFormattedPrice: function (price) {
        //todo add format data
        if (price === 0) {
            return "Free Shipping";
        }
        return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getPriceFormat());
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Override is a very bad practice, during version upgrade you will face a lot of issues,  better you should try preference or observer or create your own module.

Comment: DO NOT USE the selected answer. It's a very bad practice and it's not recommended not matter what!

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this is adding a [js mixing](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html) from a [custom module](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/).

You can install the following [module](https://github.com/araujophillips/magento2-module-freeshippinglabel) from github, or follow these steps:

**Step 1**

Create the following path in your Magento root directory: `app/code/AraujoPhillips/FreeShippingLabel`

*Note: Set the Vendor and Module name as you wish, but you will have to change them in the next steps too.*

**Step 2**

Create a `registration.php` file into `app/code/AraujoPhillips/FreeShippingLabel` with the following content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'AraujoPhillips_FreeShippingLabel',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 3**

Create a `module.xml` file into `app/code/AraujoPhillips/FreeShippingLabel/etc` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="AraujoPhillips_FreeShippingLabel" setup_version="0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Tax"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 4**

Create a `requirejs-config.js` file into `app/code/AraujoPhillips/FreeShippingLabel/view/frontend/` with the following content:

```
var config = {
    'map': {
        '*': {
        'Magento_Tax/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html':
            'AraujoPhillips_FreeShippingLabel/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html'
        }
    },
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price': {
                'AraujoPhillips_FreeShippingLabel/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

**Step 5**

Create a `price-mixin.js` file into `app/code/AraujoPhillips/FreeShippingLabel/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/` with the following content:

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils'
], function (Component, quote, priceUtils) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * Return shipping method item price
             * @param {*} price
             * @return {*|String}
             */
            getFormattedPrice: function (price) {
                if (price === 0)
                    return 'Free shipping';

                return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getPriceFormat());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

*Note: If you want to change the "Free shipping" label with anything else, do it here just before the* `if (price === 0)` *line.*

**Step 6**

Create a `price.html` file into `app/code/AraujoPhillips/FreeShippingLabel/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/shipping_method/` with the following content:

```
<!-- ko if:  isDisplayShippingPriceExclTax -->
<span class="price"><span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice(method.price_excl_tax), css: method.price_incl_tax == 0 ? 'free-shipping' : ''"></span></span>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: isDisplayShippingPriceExclTax -->
<!-- ko if:  (isDisplayShippingBothPrices && (method.price_excl_tax != method.price_incl_tax))-->
<span class="price-including-tax" data-bind = "attr: {'data-label': $t('Incl. Tax')}">
    <span class="price"><span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice(method.price_incl_tax), css: method.price_incl_tax == 0 ? 'free-shipping' : ''"></span></span>
</span>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot:  (isDisplayShippingBothPrices && (method.price_excl_tax != method.price_incl_tax))-->
    <span class="price"><span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice(method.price_incl_tax), css: method.price_incl_tax == 0 ? 'free-shipping' : ''"></span></span>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if:  (isDisplayShippingBothPrices && (method.price_excl_tax != method.price_incl_tax))-->
<span class="price-excluding-tax" data-bind = "attr: {'data-label': $t('Excl. Tax')}">
    <span class="price"><span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice(method.price_excl_tax), css: method.price_incl_tax == 0 ? 'free-shipping' : ''"></span></span>
</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

*Note 1: The file format is *`.html`*, NOT* `.phtml`*.*

*Note 2: If you want to change the *`free-shipping`* class with anything else, do it in every single line which have *`css: method.price_incl_tax == 0 ? 'free-shipping'`*. You can also add an ID or any other HTML attribute.*

**Step 7**

DO NOT forget enabling the module, flushing your caches, etc...

```
bin/magento module:enable AraujoPhillips_FreeShippingLabel
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:flush && bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping':'Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping',
            'Magento_Tax/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping':'Vendor_Module/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping',
            'Magento_Tax/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html':'Vendor_Module/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html'
        }
    },
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price-mixin.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils'
], function (Component, quote, priceUtils) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * Return shipping method item price
             * @param {*} price
             * @return {*|String}
             */
            getFormattedPrice: function (price) {
                if (price === 0) {
                    return 'FREE';
                }
                return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getPriceFormat());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ],
    function ($, Component, quote) {
        var displayMode = window.checkoutConfig.reviewShippingDisplayMode;
        return Component.extend({
            // defaults: {
            //     displayMode: displayMode,
            //     template: 'Vendor_Module/checkout/summary/shipping'
            // },
           /* Added my functions */
           isFreeShipping:function(){
                if(quote && quote.shippingMethod() && quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code) {
                    var carrierCode = quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code;
                    console.log(carrierCode);
                    if(carrierCode == "freeshipping"){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            },
            getText:function(){
                return "FREE";
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/shipping.html

```
<!-- Added custom functions with core function -->
    <!-- ko if: isFreeShipping() -->
    <tr class="totals shipping excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: title"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getShippingMethodTitle()"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">
            <span  class="price" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;" data-bind="text: getText(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: isFreeShipping() -->
    <tr class="totals shipping excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: title"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getShippingMethodTitle()"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">
            <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html

```
<!-- ko if:  isDisplayShippingPriceExclTax -->
<span class="price"><span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice(method.price_excl_tax), css: method.price_incl_tax == 0 ? 'free-shipping' : ''"></span></span>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: isDisplayShippingPriceExclTax -->
<!-- ko if:  (isDisplayShippingBothPrices && (method.price_excl_tax != method.price_incl_tax))-->
<span class="price-including-tax" data-bind = "attr: {'data-label': $t('Incl. Tax')}">
    <span class="price"><span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice(method.price_incl_tax), css: method.price_incl_tax == 0 ? 'free-shipping' : ''"></span></span>
</span>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot:  (isDisplayShippingBothPrices && (method.price_excl_tax != method.price_incl_tax))-->
    <span class="price"><span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice(method.price_incl_tax), css: method.price_incl_tax == 0 ? 'free-shipping' : ''"></span></span>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if:  (isDisplayShippingBothPrices && (method.price_excl_tax != method.price_incl_tax))-->
<span class="price-excluding-tax" data-bind = "attr: {'data-label': $t('Excl. Tax')}">
    <span class="price"><span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice(method.price_excl_tax), css: method.price_incl_tax == 0 ? 'free-shipping' : ''"></span></span>
</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```